# Getting size of knockout views from dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, d3.js, coffeescript

In my knockout app, i have a portion of it that resembles this structure:

```
<section class="container">
  <section class="percent-sizes">
     <article class="d3Graph"></article>
  </section> 
  .
  .
  .
  <section class="percent-sizes">
     <article class="d3Graph"></article>
  </section> 
</section>
```

These `<sections>` are dynamic, they can be created on the fly.

Essentially I have a bunch of `<sections>` which take up **percentage** portions of the screen, depending on how many there are, and then in each one I have d3 graphs, of which I have to know the **pixel** sizes in order to draw them.

Each one of these sections has it's own ViewModel, and the container has it's own, and maintains a observableArray of it's children.

When a new `<section>` is created, I need to know via knockout what the widths/heights of the `<sections>` are and redraw them.

What is the knockout best practice for this?  (i'd rather not calculate the percentages by hand, or use jquery selectors to find the elements and query their height manually.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not have them all contained inside of an observableArray and just set the height as a computed value such as this -

```
function whateverViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.height = ko.computed(function () {
        return (1 / sectionContainer.length);
    });
}

var sectionContainer = ko.observableArray();

sectionContainer.push(new whateverViewModel());

<section data-bind="style: { height: height }"></section>
```